# Swift - NSTimer passing wrong value for userInfo param

Tags: ios, swift2, nstimer

I recently took it upon myself to learn the Swift programming language and I love it.  To help me learn, I have been working on a couple of simple apps using XCode 7.  One of those apps is a flashlight and one of the features is a strobe light.  I decided on using the NSTimer class to schedule the flashlight toggle functionality to be called at a set time interval, thus giving a nice strobe effect.  My first crack at the timer code is as follows :-

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self.torch, selector: "toggleTorch:", userInfo: false, repeats: true)
```

As you can see here, I am using my own custom made Torch object to handle the flash toggle functionality.  I pass the torch object I have specified as an instance variable as the target param and then I call the following function in the Torch class, which I pass as selector :-

```
func toggleTorch(adjustingBrightness: Bool) -> Bool {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    defer {
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }

    guard device.hasTorch else {
        return false
    }
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()

        if  !adjustingBrightness && device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
        }
        else if !adjustingBrightness && device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.Off {
            try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(brightnessLevel)
        }               
        else if adjustingBrightness && device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On {
            try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(brightnessLevel)
        }
    } catch {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that when the timer calls the `toggleTorch` method, it is passing the value of `true` as the parameter even though I have specifically passed `false` to the timer as the `userInfo` param.

So I scratch my head and think "Ah" let's try using a default value of `false` in the selector/method parameter and pass `nil` in the timer `userInfo` param.  That way I can rely on the default value of `false` being invoked every time.  So my new selector signature looks as follows:-

```
func toggleTorch(adjustingBrightness: Bool = false) -> Bool
```

And the timer that now calls it has changed to:-

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self.torch, selector: "toggleTorch:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

However, despite the default parameter and no parameter passing going on via the timer, the value being passed through is still `true`.  So I tinker some more and decide to see if using my ViewController as the target object will make a difference.  I place a new selector in my ViewController like so:-

```
func toggleTorch() {
    torch.toggleTorch(false)
}
```

I then update my timer to call this new method within the ViewController :-

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "toggleTorch", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

'Hey Presto' it now works fine and the correct boolean value of `false` is being passed because I have passed the value myself.  Why is this happening?  For info, I'v been learning Swift for about three wks so am no expert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTimer` does not pass the `userInfo` information as the parameter to the selector. It passes itself as the parameter so that you know which timer was called.

You should set it up as follows:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self.torch, selector: "strobeTimerFired:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And have a method as follows in your Torch object:

```
func strobeTimerFired(timer: NSTimer) {
    toggleTorch(false)
}
```

In this case you don't need to access the timer object in the `strobeTimerFired` method, but it's good practise to include it anyway (it can be skipped). You could add additional checking to ensure the timer that triggered the method is the one you expected for example.

If you did need to use the `userInfo` for something, (don't think you'd need it in this case), you could pass an object in the original `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` call as the `userInfo` parameter, and then you would access that in the `strobeTimerFired` method by accessing: `timer.userInfo`.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this and mark as accepted answer it it works fine.  It confused me because the user info parameter is an Optional AnyObject.  If it was actually specified to be an NSTimer in the signature I may have sussed it.  The Apple class reference didn't explain well enough for my liking at all but then hey I'm still learning. I'm sure there's a good reason for that

Comment: The userInfo is an optional AnyObject. That's not where the NSTimer goes. You can pass anything in as userInfo and use it inside the called selector, just not as the parameter to the called selector. That's always the NSTimer object calling the selector.

Comment: Aha now I see.  Thanks Dave.  Much appreciated.  Have a great New Year!

Comment: One more question Dave if you don't mind,  but it's niggling at me. I originally wrote the selector function without NSTimer as the param and I should have done.  Why wouldn't it blow up and tell me so at runtime when the timer invoked the selector and found the incorrect param type?  And secondly, how has it determined the Bool I have passed to be true.  In Java we have default values.  boolean isTrue; would be false if declared but not initialised explicitly.  The selector expects an NSTimer.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say at the end...I could understand if the selector took AnyObject as a param. It's the superclass.. We've got it covered. But i'v clearly specified it to be a Bool.

Comment: NSTimer will use the dispatch system to trigger the call to the selector and it passes the NSTimer object to it as the parameter. You've specified the type to be Bool, but that's at the compiler level, and the check isn't done by the dispatch system. So the NSTimer object would be a non-nil value, which would be treated as true by your selector. Hope that helps.